Не запускается редактор SQLite
Вчера делал проект на с# с БД в редакторе SQLite Studio. В итоге в моменте делаю проект и редактор просто выключился сам по себе, без ошибок без ничего. Пытался снова запустить не запускается вообще, не от имени админа, никак. Пробовал переустанавливать, не помогло. Думал, что майнер может блокировать (что вряд-ли). В итоге майнеры удалил, но проблема всё такая же. Уже не знаю что делать. Начал систему обновлять ибо в интернете писали, что возможно нужно систему обновить. Но всё же, подскажите что за проблема может быть. Если кратко, то не запускается редактор SQlite Studio. Система у меня: win11 на х64.
